Keep richtext codeblock identation and style to chatter feed item
Hi I'm trying to use a richtext in a lwc, in order to accept code snippets (String) denoted by triple single quotes like this:

The lwc takes the richtext value and create a chatter feed item through connected API.
However chatter feed item does not accept the same tags that richtext does, And Im trying to keep identation and styling, once the feed item is created with the given String.
I know that what the standard </> feature of chatter does is embed the string in  tags, so Im cleaning the html tags for the segment in the richtext-area denoted by triple single quotes and then embed it in [cleaned snippet code string] tags.
The problem is that the resulting post is this:

No identation, colors are not treated correctly when a comment is found. Is there a way that using Connected API, apex or something I could get a decent identation and coloring?. I tried to also use  tag in the final string (the one sended to the connectedAPI segment) but it throws an error saying  tag is not supported.
